# Machine learning systems

Tags: machine-learning

As per Pedro Domingos in his famous paper "A Few Useful Things to Know about Machine Learning" he writes ***Machine learning systems automatically learn programs from data.***

But from my experience we r giving algorithms like ANN or SVM etc.

My question is how it is automating automation?

Could someone put some light with example.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you develop a machine learning algorithm, with ANN or SVM or whatever, you don't say to your programming how to solve your problem, you are telling him how to learn to solve the problem.
SVM or ANN are ways to learn a solution to a problem, but not how to solve a problem.
So when people say "Machine learning systems automatically learn programs from data", they are saying that you never programmed a solution to your problem, but rather letting the computer learning to do so.

To quote wikipedia : "Machine learning is a field of computer science that gives computers the ability to learn without being explicitly programmed"

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Machine_learning

[Edit]

For example let's take one of the most simple machine learning algorithm, the linear regression in a 2D space.
The aim of this algorithm is to learn a linear function given a dataset of `(x,y)`, so when you given your system a new `x` you get an approximation of what the real `y` would be.

But when you code a linear regression you never specify the linear function `y = ax+b`. What you code is a way for the program to deduce it from the dataset.

The linear function `y=ax+b` is the solution to your problem, the linear regression code is the way you are going to learn that solution.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_regression

Comment: Very impressive answer could u please provide with a detailed example.Many Many thanks  for your answer.

Comment: I added an example, i hope it is clear enough.

Comment: thanks for your clear explanation.

Comment: as per u we never specify y=ax+b means we r not giving values of a,b but we r specifying the formula through linear regression model using some library(ex slklearn linear rgression).Am i ri8?

Answer (score 1):

*[Machine Learning development](http://danniwynn.doodlekit.com/blog/entry/4238065/top-ways-how-machine-learning-help-business-grow)* helps to improve business operations as well as improve business scalability. A number of ML algorithms and artificial intelligence tools have gained tremendous popularity in the community of business analytics. There has been a rise in machine learning market due to faster and cheaper computational processing, easy availability of data as well as affordable data storage.